# How run pytest after pywinauto in script

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, pywinauto

I run my pywinauto test and I want the pytest to run after it. Now i run it with pycharm (Run->Edit configurations->Before launch:Activate tool window->Add run another configuration), but i want to run it with script.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHBAC.png

In case1.py i tried:

```
subprocess.call(["python","tests\\test_xml_filename.py"])
os.system('C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pywinauto\\venv\\Scripts\\python C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pywinauto\\tests\\test_xml_filename.py')
```

but it still not work

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean under `not work`? What is expected?

Comment: I run a pywinauto script, after ending i runing the script for pytest. I would like to do this automatically. The command that called does not run the pytest script

Comment: And what is the error output? I see only one script `test_xml_filename.py` is mentioned. But no content of this script provided. This is too small info.

Comment: Pywinauto in script "case1.py" work is correct. In end this file "case1.py" i write by example os.system... he does start "test_xml_filename.py". In pycharm console "Process finished with exit code 0". Sorry, all works is fine, but file "test_xml_filename.py" with pytest not output in console, i add additional arguments "-s" for script "test_xml_filename.py" but he not show "test session start with message pass or fail". I think file "test_xml_filename.py" should run with pytest. How it doing in script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to pywinauto. Just use `subprocess.check_output(...)`.

```
output = subprocess.check_output("<your command>")
print(output)
```

Real-time passing stdout from child to parent process is not easy implementable. Why not using import script as a module and call dedicated function? One process, one stdout - it's much easier to maintain.